# Unable to get this form to submit in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I get no errors with my current code.

```
var app = angular.module('mgcrea.ngStrapDocs', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

angular.module('mgcrea.ngStrapDocs')
 .controller('NavbarDemoCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
   $scope.$location = $location;

 });

app.controller ('formController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.processForm = function () {
      console.log('Click');
      $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url    : '/users/login',
            data   : $scope.formData
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function() {
            console.log("ERROR")
        });
   }
}]);
use strict;
```

I confirmed that the url: localhosts/users/login accepts post data via Postman. However, grouping everything together I find that I cannot actually submit the form to the api. I am not sure if there is some conflicting code or what specifically is the issue as I mentioned before I am not currently getting any errors.

Also, here is a paste bin link to the [html](http://pastebin.com/ALqprj40) if there seems to be no issue with the js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your markup. There are a few things to fix.

The first is to specify the name of the Angular module you are using for your application via the `ng-app` directive. In your case, this appears to be "mgcrea.ngStrapDocs". So your `<html>` tag becomes:

```
<html ng-app="mgcrea.ngStrapDocs">
```

Second, you are not telling Angular to use your controller at all in your markup. In your case, the easiest way to do this it to specify it using `ng-controller` on your `<form>` tag:

```
<form ng-controller="formController" ng-submit="processForm()">
```

Comment: I get a module error which the stack trace prints off a list of the JavaScript srcs in the markup. Would this imply that I am missing a dependency somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like you are missing the `ngSanitise` file. If you don't need it, just remove the `'ngSanitise'` entry from the array on the first line (`var app = angular.module(...`).